# Do Spark RDD's have something similar to set allowing rapid lookup?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have some data consisting of pairs such as

```
data = [(3,7), (2,4), (7,3), ...]
```

These correspond to connections in a graph I want to build. I want to keep only the pairs whose reverse pair is contained in the data, and only one copy of each. For instance, in the above data, I want [(3,7)] because the reverse ((7,3)) is also in the data.

In Python, I would do something like this:

```
pairs = set(data)
edges = [p for p in pairs if p[0] < p[1] and (p[1], p[0]) in pairs]
```

Can I do something similar on Spark? The closest I can get is creating a new RDD with the pairs reversed, taking the intersection with the original data, and filtering based on pair elements being sorted, but that seems inefficient.

Answer (score -1):

<-- language: python -->

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(3, 7), (2, 4), (7, 3)]) \
    .map(lambda x: ((min(x), max(x)), [x])) \
    .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y) \
    .filter(lambda x: len(x[1]) > 1) \
    .map(lambda x: x[0])
```

this can work as well

Comment: Did you try running this? This gives [(3,7), (2,4)], but I specified the desired result is [(3,7)].